# Is it possible to apply alt tags to lightbox images?

Tags: html, lightbox, image-gallery, alt

I have a light box with each image pointing to its respective gallery, coded in as:

```
<a href="images/properties/neighbourhood.jpg" data-lightbox="Properties"></a>
```

Is there a way that I can add `alt` tags to these images that will get crawled by Google even though they are not coded in with `img`?

Comment: you could put the alt on the thumbnail image? also does lightbox not allow for a title (which means you don't really need an alt)

Comment: Would I apply the `title` tag to each link or to just then thumbnail in that case?

Comment: I would apply the title tag to the link (so it shows on the lightbox popup) and an alt tag to the thumbnail (for your seo)

Comment: Alright awesome! Thanks for the breakdown.